# 12.04 doesn't recognize pendrive

Tags: 12.04, usb-drive

I have new pendrive which I've used few hours ago. Now my Ubuntu (12.04) doesn't recognize it. USB ports are right because other devices plugged to them works.
When I check `lsusb`, it returns:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 03f0:7104 Hewlett-Packard DeskJet 3420c
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 12d1:140c Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f3:0103 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 058f:1234 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
```

When I use `fdisk` there is no sign of my pendrive on returned list. I think it's device problem because Windows also doens't see it, but I don't know if I can do anything.

I can add that pendrive is very hot when it's plugged.

Answer (score 4):

Insert the pendrive, then in a terminal, run `dmesg`.

If your system in any way detected the device being connected, you should see something vaguely like (copied from [Ubuntu docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsbDriveDoSomethingHowto)):

```
[17197212.184000] usb 5-6: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 2
[17197212.420000] Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
[17197212.420000] scsi2 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
[17197212.420000] usb-storage: device found at 2
[17197212.420000] usb-storage: waiting for device to settle before scanning
[17197212.420000] usbcore: registered new driver usb-storage
[17197212.420000] USB Mass Storage support registered.
[17197217.420000]   Vendor: WDC WD32  Model: 00JB-00KFA0       Rev: 0811
[17197217.420000]   Type:   Direct-Access                      ANSI SCSI revision: 00
[17197217.436000] usb-storage: device scan complete
[17197217.464000] Driver 'sd' needs updating - please use bus_type methods
[17197217.472000] SCSI device sda: 625142448 512-byte hdwr sectors (320073 MB)
[17197217.472000] sda: assuming drive cache: write through
[17197217.520000] SCSI device sda: 625142448 512-byte hdwr sectors (320073 MB)
[17197217.520000] sda: assuming drive cache: write through
[17197217.520000]  sda: sda1
[17197217.528000] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi disk sda
[17197217.540000] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
```

If there is **nothing** mentioning USB activity after inserting it, I think this would imply the device is dead. However, you might see some output indicating that a device was detecting and why it was unable to be mounted, if it is an error condition Linux understands.

A very hot device that is unrecognised by windows and linux however sounds a lot like something has shorted out and there is not a lot you can do.

Comment: Thanks, there is some information about my flash drive, but I don't know what to do.
Information which I've received: [link](http://pastebin.pl/65266)

Comment: In my opinion, something in the pendrive is shorting resulting in the dissipation of heat. Suggest you do not use the pendrive anymore.

Answer (score 0):

its the same case with me, pen drive doesn't come in Ubuntu 12.04 but gets detected in Windows.
I will check it with dmesg and will report back